# Big json(like 100MB) to excel in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'am new to REST technology. I'm currently dealing with a json response from a server and presenting the data on the client side.

I am now getting around 22MB of json data, and I need to export it to an excel sheet.

**My problem:**

When I'm iterating to json , the browser is not responding. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is your question? It might help you to look at the topic of [how to write a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for us to be able to help you.

Comment: Iterate JSON in batches

Comment: Browsers hang and show 'Stop slow running script' dialog if huge processing is done without giving back a response to the browser. Refer my answer to avoid slow running script..

Comment: What file type do you want exactly? How are you doing it, any code? What structure do you expect to come out? Please describe carefully to let others understand your question. Do it quick or someone **will** downvote you ;)

Comment: I have got some idea through answer...thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**IDEALLY, you should not be exporting such a big excel file for download. You must be breaking the data to chunks and asking user to download in batches. However, if it may be a part of your requirement, to handle it, refer answer below.**

**You might have to download the json in batches and combine as a single excel file and ask user to download!**

The unresponsive script dialog box shows when some javascript thread takes too long too complete.  Editing the registry could work, but you would have to do it on all client machines.  You could use a "recursive closure" as follows to alleviate the problem.  It's just a coding structure in which allows you to take a long running for loop and change it into something that does some work, and keeps track where it left off, yielding to the browser, then continuing where it left off until we are done.

**Figure 1, Add this Utility Class RepeatingOperation to your javascript file.  You will not need to change this code:**

```
RepeatingOperation = function(op, yieldEveryIteration) {

  //keeps count of how many times we have run heavytask() 
  //before we need to temporally check back with the browser.
  var count = 0;   

  this.step = function() {

    //Each time we run heavytask(), increment the count. When count
    //is bigger than the yieldEveryIteration limit, pass control back 
    //to browser and instruct the browser to immediately call op() so
    //we can pick up where we left off.  Repeat until we are done.
    if (++count >= yieldEveryIteration) {
      count = 0;

      //pass control back to the browser, and in 1 millisecond, 
      //have the browser call the op() function.  
      setTimeout(function() { op(); }, 1, [])

      //The following return statement halts this thread, it gives 
      //the browser a sigh of relief, your long-running javascript
      //loop has ended (even though technically we havn't yet).
      //The browser decides there is no need to alarm the user of
      //an unresponsive javascript process.
      return;
      }
    op();
  };
};
```

**Figure 2, The following code represents your code that is causing the 'stop running this script' dialog because it takes so long to complete:**

```
process10000HeavyTasks = function() {
  var len = 10000;  
  for (var i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    heavytask();   //heavytask() can be run about 20  times before
                   //an 'unresponsive script' dialog appears.
                   //If heavytask() is run more than 20 times in one
                   //javascript thread, the browser informs the user that
                   //an unresponsive script needs to be dealt with.  

                   //This is where we need to terminate this long running
                   //thread, instruct the browser not to panic on an unresponsive
                   //script, and tell it to call us right back to pick up
                   //where we left off.
  }
}
```

**Figure 3.  The following code is the fix for the problematic code in Figure 2.  Notice the for loop is replaced with a recursive closure which passes control back to the browser every 10 iterations of heavytask()**

```
process10000HeavyTasks = function() {

  var global_i = 10000; //initialize your 'for loop stepper' (i) here.

  var repeater = new this.RepeatingOperation(function() {

    heavytask();

    if (--global_i >= 0){     //Your for loop conditional goes here.
      repeater.step();        //while we still have items to process,
                              //run the next iteration of the loop.
    }
    else {
       alert("we are done");  //when this line runs, the for loop is complete.
    }
  }, 10);                   //10 means process 10 heavytask(), then
                            //yield back to the browser, and have the
                            //browser call us right back.

  repeater.step();          //this command kicks off the recursive closure.

};
```

Adapted from this source:

http://www.picnet.com.au/blogs/Guido/post/2010/03/04/How-to-prevent-Stop-running-this-script-message-in-browsers